# Why doesn't the Discriminator's and Generators' loss change?

Tags: python, pytorch, mnist, loss, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to implement a Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) for the MNIST-Dataset.
I use Pytorch for this. My problem is, that after one epoch the Discriminator's and the Generator's loss doesn't change.

I already tried two other methods to build the network, but they cause all the same problem :/

```py
import os
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as grd
import numpy as np
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn as nn 
import torch.nn.functional as F 
import torchvision #Datasets
from torchvision.utils import save_image
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
import pylab

#Parameter
batch_size = 64
epochs = 50000
image_size = 784
hidden_size = 392
sample_dir = 'samples'
save_dir = 'save'
noise_size = 100
lr = 0.001

# Image processing
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5,),(0.5,))])

# Discriminator
D = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(image_size, hidden_size),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1),
    nn.Sigmoid()
)

# Generator
G = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(noise_size, hidden_size),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(hidden_size, image_size),
    nn.Sigmoid()
)

# Lossfunction and optimizer (sigmoid cross entropy with logits and Adam)
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
d_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(D.parameters(), lr = lr)
g_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(G.parameters(), lr = lr)

def reset_grad():
    d_optimizer.zero_grad()
    g_optimizer.zero_grad()

# Statistics to be saved
d_losses = np.zeros(epochs)
g_losses = np.zeros(epochs)
real_scores = np.zeros(epochs)
fake_scores = np.zeros(epochs)

# Start training
total_step = len(data_loader)
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for i, (images, _) in enumerate(data_loader):
        if images.shape[0] != 64:
            continue
        images = images.view(batch_size, -1).cuda()
        images = Variable(images)
        # Create the labels which are later used as input for the BCE loss
        real_labels = torch.ones(batch_size, 1).cuda()
        real_labels = Variable(real_labels)
        fake_labels = torch.zeros(batch_size, 1).cuda()
        fake_labels = Variable(fake_labels)

        # Train discriminator

        # Compute BCE_WithLogitsLoss using real images 
        outputs = D(images)
        d_loss_real = criterion(outputs, real_labels)
        real_score = outputs

        # Compute BCE_WithLogitsLoss using fake images
        # First term of the loss is always zero since fake_labels == 0
        z = torch.randn(batch_size, noise_size).cuda()
        z = Variable(z)
        fake_images = G(z)
        outputs = D(fake_images)
        d_loss_fake = criterion(outputs, fake_labels)
        fake_score = outputs

        # Backprop and optimize
        # If D is trained so well, then don't update
        d_loss = d_loss_real + d_loss_fake
        reset_grad()
        d_loss.backward()
        d_optimizer.step()

        # Train generator 

        # Compute loss with fake images
        z = torch.randn(batch_size, noise_size).cuda()
        z = Variable(z)
        fake_images = G(z)
        outputs = D(fake_images)

        # We train G to maximize log(D(G(z)) instead of minimizing log(1 -D(G(z)))
        # For the reason, see the last paragraph of section 3. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf
        g_loss = criterion(outputs, real_labels)

        # Backprop and optimize
        # if G is trained so well, then don't update
        reset_grad()
        g_loss.backward()
        g_optimizer.step()

        # Update statistics

        d_losses[epoch] = d_losses[epoch]*(i/(i+1.)) + d_loss.item()*(1./(i+1.))
        g_losses[epoch] = g_losses[epoch]*(i/(i+1.)) + g_loss.item()*(1./(i+1.))
        real_scores[epoch] = real_scores[epoch]*(i/(i+1.)) + real_score.mean().item()*(1./(i+1.))
        fake_scores[epoch] = fake_scores[epoch]*(i/(i+1.)) + fake_score.mean().item()*(1./(i+1.))

    # print results
    print('Epoch [{}/{}], d_loss: {:.4f}, g_loss: {:.4f}, D(x): {:.2f}, D(G(z)): {:.2f}' 
            .format(epoch, epochs, d_loss.item(), g_loss.item(), 
                    real_score.mean().item(), fake_score.mean().item()))
```

The Generator's and Discriminator's loss should change from epoch to epoch, but they don't.

```
Epoch [0/50000], d_loss: 1.0069, g_loss: 0.6927, D(x): 1.00, D(G(z)): 0.00
Epoch [1/50000], d_loss: 1.0065, g_loss: 0.6931, D(x): 1.00, D(G(z)): 0.00
Epoch [2/50000], d_loss: 1.0064, g_loss: 0.6931, D(x): 1.00, D(G(z)): 0.00
Epoch [3/50000], d_loss: 1.0064, g_loss: 0.6931, D(x): 1.00, D(G(z)): 0.00
Epoch [4/50000], d_loss: 1.0064, g_loss: 0.6931, D(x): 1.00, D(G(z)): 0.00
Epoch [5/50000], d_loss: 1.0064, g_loss: 0.6931, D(x): 1.00, D(G(z)): 0.00
```

Thank's for your help.

Comment: One probable cause that comes to mind is that you're simultaneously training discriminator and generator. This will cause discriminator to become much stronger, therefore it's harder (nearly impossible) for generator to beat it, and there's no room for improvement for discriminator. Usually generator network is trained more frequently than the discriminator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used a template from another GAN to build mine. The template works fine. I just changed the deep of the models and the activation and loss function to rebuild a tensorflow implementation from a bachelor thesis I have to use in my thesis in PyTorch. Both, the template and the tensorflow implementation work fine.

Comment: Why the `real_score` and `fake_score` is 1.0 and 0.0 respectively? These scores are the average of Sigmoid scores. How their mean can be 1.0 and 0.0? Also, did you check whether the weight-parameters of your model are changing?

Answer (score 3):

I found out the solution of the problem.
BCEWithLogitsLoss() and Sigmoid() doesn't work together, because BCEWithLogitsLoss() includes the Sigmoid activation.
So you can use BCEWithLogitsLoss() without Sigmoid() or you can use Sigmoid() and BCELoss()

Comment: I would not recommend using Sigmoid for GAN's discriminator though.